# Machine Learning in R. Calculation of Estimate Value

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have train.csv file with data: YEAR, FUEL_TYPE, VIN_1, CONDITION, AVERAGE_COST, ESTIMATE COST.

- YEAR - year when car was manufactured(Factor w/ 20 levels).
- FUEL_TYPE - type of fuel of car (Factor w/ 5 levels).
- VIN_1 - 1st number of vin of car (Factor w/ 24 levels).
- CONDITION - condition of car (Factor w/ 3 levels).
- AVERAGE_COST - average cost of car( Factor w/ 6950 levels).
- ESTIMATE_COST - estimate cost of car depending on factors. ( Factor w/ 2328 levels)

Example: [image]

So in test.csv I have everything that I have in train.csv except ESTIMATE_COST. So I have to find out what will be estimate cost of cars in test.csv, analysing train.csv. I watched and read Titanic example, but my task looks a bit different. I'm using Rstudio and trying RandomForest. But how to calculate ESTIM_COST by random forest?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. The general workflow is to load both files, train a model using `randomForest()`, then apply it to the test data using `predict()`. It would help if you narrowed down your question to a specific issue and showed the code you have so far. Take a look at the following for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can we talk in messenger or smth like that?